# Redirect stdout of a killed executable

Tags: c, linux, bash, terminal, pipe

I have a C file that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello world\n");
   while (1);
   return 0;
}
```

And I would like to see "Hello world" printed in a new file. But it doesn't work when I try to redirect the standard output like this:

```
./hello_world >> logfile &
```

And then kill the program hello_world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush stdout before the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello world\n");
   fflush(stdout);
   while (1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works this way. However I don't understand way. I thought the `\n` in `printf` already flushed stdout as it occurs in the terminal.

Comment: Newline flushes the output directed to a terminal. Your output is directed to a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see output as it occurs, use fflush(stdout); after your printf().